# How to define 'value' property setter parameter

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

With the following C# code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Bar
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

the property setter signature compiles to:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname newslot abstract virtual 
    instance void set_X (
        int32 'value'
    ) cil managed 
{
}
```

when inspected with ILSpy or ildasm.

If I attempt to generate an identical method signature using the `System.Reflection.Emit` API, the resulting input parameter name is either empty:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname newslot abstract virtual 
    instance void set_X (
        int32 ''
    ) cil managed 
{
}
```

<sup>(signature generated by `ilspy`)</sup>

... or a seemingly generated reference name (`A_1` in this case):

```
.method public hidebysig newslot specialname abstract virtual 
    instance void  set_X(
        int32 A_1
    ) cil managed
{
}
```

<sup>(signature generated by `ildasm`)</sup>

How can I give the input parameter the name "value" like in the C# compiled example?

---

Here's the code I've used to generate the setter with:

```
PropertyBuilder property = typeDef.DefineProperty("X", PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof(int), null);

MethodAttributes ma = MethodAttributes.Public 
                    | MethodAttributes.HideBySig 
                    | MethodAttributes.NewSlot 
                    | MethodAttributes.SpecialName 
                    | MethodAttributes.Abstract 
                    | MethodAttributes.Virtual;
MethodBuilder setMethod = typeDef.DefineMethod("set_X", ma, CallingConventions.HasThis, null, new[] { typeof(int) });

property.SetSetMethod(setMethod);
```

Even when I explicitly attempt to define the parameter name, the result is still the same:

```
MethodBuilder setMethod = typeDef.DefineMethod("set_X", ma, CallingConventions.HasThis, null, new[] { typeof(int) });

ParameterBuilder pb = setMethod.DefineParameter(0, ParameterAttributes.None, "value");

property.SetSetMethod(setMethod);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use index `1` for the first parameter. From the msdn entry for [MethodBuilder.DefineParameter Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.defineparameter?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Reflection_Emit_MethodBuilder_DefineParameter_System_Int32_System_Reflection_ParameterAttributes_System_String_):

> **Remarks**
>
> [...]
>
> Parameter numbering begins with 1, so *position* is 1 for the first parameter. If *position* is zero, this method affects the return value.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!